# Create .csv or .txt with source/copyright infomation in first couple of lines to export from shiny

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, shiny

I am creating a shiny app for people to download results of our study. I have set up everything within shiny for users to create their own database and a download button to return a csv of their results. However, I need to include some copyright information at the top of the outputted csv file, ideally like this:

```
Source: Data from us.
Copyright: Us.

Age   Sex      Size  
1     Male     10
2     Male     4
[...more rows...]
100   Female   1
```

I am struggling to get `write.table` or `write.csv` to provide me with this format. They both put the column headers (Age, Sex, Size) at the top of page. Also when I view the csv in Excel the first cell only displays 'Source: D'. I can not seem to get the text to continue over to the next empty cell when I use `na=" "` in `write.csv`

Comment: If I were you, I would consider putting that in a separate README or COPYRIGHT.txt, and export everything in a zip file.

Comment: agreed. it's not my call though, its how the boss wants it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a file connection. Something like this for the `content` sub inside `downloadHandler`:

```
content = function(filename) {
  fh <- file(filename, "w")
  cat(copyright_str, file = fh)
  write.csv(data, fh, row.names = FALSE)
  close(fh)
}
```

where

```
copyright_str <- '"Source: Data from us."\n"Copyright: Us."\n\n'
```

Comment: lovely. didn't know `cat` can go outside the R console.